# Move anchor point of image to its center

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have an `airports.json` file with airport coordinates and want to attach an `airport.svg` icon at each of these coordinates on a map with the function:

```
function draw_airports() {

  d3.json('airports.json').then(function(airport_data) {
    var svg = d3
      .select('map_container')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    var g = svg.append('g');

    var img = g
        .selectAll('img')
        .data(airport_data)
        .enter()
        .append('svg:image')
        .attr('xlink:href', 'airport.svg')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
           return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
        })
        .attr('width', 8)
        .attr('height', 8);
  });
```

This code attaches the icon to the right of and below its coordinates on the map.
How can I move the anchor point (0,0) of `airport.svg` to the center of the icon?

Coordinate space of airport.svg:

[image: Coordinate space of airport.svg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a line:

```
.attr('transform', 'translate(-4,-4)')
```

after assigning the `width` / `height` attributes to the icon. The value of translate's x and y depends of the icon's width and height. It should be: x = -width/2, y = -height/2.